# Is there a way to have an updated drop down menu that pull records from database using php

Tags: php, database, drop-down-menu

```
<?php
$sql="select software from software_table";
$qry=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($qry);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($qry);
$data=['software_name'];
?>
<?php
for($i=0; $i<=count($data); $i++){
?>
<select name="software_name">
<option vale="<?php echo $data[$i]?>">$data</option>
}
?>
```

`I dont know if this is possible, but what I want to happen is that, when I add new software from software_table. My drop-down menu for software will get its option value from the database to become updated. I am thinking to use For-Loop for this, but I dont know how to start or is it really possible.

example.
in my drop-down menu. i have 3 option value.

```
1.MS OFFICE
2.AUTODESK
3.PRIMAVERA
```

and then I add another software from the database which is WINDOWS 8.

I want my drop-down menu to have those 4 value.

Comment: We are here to help in fixing errors not to writing the code!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following code -

```
$sql="select software from software_table";
$qry=mysql_query($sql); ?>
<select name="software_name">
<?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry)) {
    $data=$row['software_name']; ?>
    <option vale="<?php echo $data; ?>"><?php echo $data; ?></option>
<?php }
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="software_name">
<?php
$sql="select software from software_table";
$qry=mysql_query($sql);
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry))
{
    // In your case, each row contains only one value: $row[0] = the value of software field
    echo "<option vale=\"$row[0]\">$row[0]</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

This will generate the HTML code as:

```
<select name="software_name">
    <option vale="MS OFFICE">MS OFFICE</option>
    <option vale="AUTODESK">AUTODESK</option>
    <option vale="PRIMAVERA">PRIMAVERA</option>
</select>
```

Comment: A little description to go with the answer would have been more helpful.